# Sum of Dirichlet's Character Over Divisors of Natural Number

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory

It is said in [Explanation for a theorem pertaining on Dirichlet character sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728787/explanation-for-a-theorem-pertaining-on-dirichlet-character-sums) it is well-known that $A\left(n\right)=\sum_{d\mid n}\chi\left(d\right)$ is non-negative for $\chi$ is character modulo $k$, and $\geq 1$ when $n$ is square-free. Where can I find the proof for this fact?

Comment: Dirichlet characters are completely multiplicative. Use this to factor your sum into a product of expressions involving the character. Assuming you mean quadratic characters, this quantity should indeed be non-negative.

Comment: Note that you need to ensure $\chi$ is real as well

Comment: @TravorLZH if $\chi$ is complex the statement does not true? Do you have an example?

Comment: @mrsobama Oh I see, I didn't remember it's completely multiplicative, thank you.

Comment: I'll say it's not necessarily true because in this case you can't ensure the result of the Dirichlet convolution is real

Comment: @TravorLZH I see, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of this result is available in chapter 6 of Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*. In the book, the result is labeled as **Theorem 6.19**.